# post-receive: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, git, amazon-ec2

I'm getting an error when trying to push to a remote Amazon EC2 (Ubuntu Linux) instance.  I've given all related directories and files full permissions. I'm trying to use a post-receive hook to move the project to my production directory at `/var/www/myapp`:

```
$ git push prod-server master

Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 292 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: cannot run hooks/post-receive: No such file or directory
To prod-server:/home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp.git
   8944048..a445d1d  master -> master
```

My post-receive file (located in bare repository: `/home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp.git/hooks/`):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
  branch=`echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3`
  if [ "prod-server" == "$branch" -o "master" == "$branch" ]; then
    git --work-tree=/var/www/myapp/ checkout -f $branch
    echo 'Changes pushed to Amazon EC2 PROD-SERVER directory!'
  fi
  if [ "test" == "$branch" ]; then
    git --work-tree=/var/www/myapp/test/ checkout -f $branch
    echo 'Changes pushed to Amazon EC2 PROD-SERVER test directory!'
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with the `post-receive` script not being in the right place. What is the output of `git remote -v` in the local repository and `ls -l /home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp.git/hooks` on the server?

Some tips for the script itself:

- [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)
- Bash (and POSIX shells) use a single equals sign for `[`
- `-o` is [deprecated](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_05); you should instead use `[ foo = bar ] || [ baz = ban ]`
- Use `set -o errexit` to exit the script at the first error; it should make debugging much easier
- Use `set -o xtrace` and `exec > /tmp/post-receive.log 2>&1` to (temporarily) get a debug log of what the script does.